# Process all the template questions in django view at once

Tags: python, django

## Hi Everyone! i am a newbie.Using the django documentation example, how do i process all the questions in #the views.py

## Template:

```html
<html>

<body>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
  <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
  {% if error_message %}
  <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
  </p>
  {% endif %}
  <form id="qform" action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" id=”choice{{ forloop.counter }} " value="{{ choice.id }}” />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
    <br/>{% endfor %}
  </form>
  {% endfor %}
  <input form="qform" type="submit" value="Vote" />
</body>

</html>
```

## views.py(this is not working!)

```
def vote(request, question_id): 
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id) 
    try: 
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST[question.id])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):  
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', { 'question':
         question, 'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.", }) 
    else: selected_choice.votes += 1 selected_choice.save()  
        return render(request,'polls/results.html', {'question':question,
         'selected_choice': selected_choice, 'error_message': error_message})
```

## models.py

```
class Question(models.Model): 
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(‘date published’)


class Choice(models.Model): 
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question) 
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

## forms.py

```
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
        'question_text',
        'choices',
        ]

    choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Question.choice_set, widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

## Kindly tell me what i am missing; i need help badly. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

You used separate form for every question, but browsers accept only one form to send for server, you must use django [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) for this type of issues.

**Update:**
Also this notice that you placed only one input on every form is important, you can do this by some changes and without **Django Formsets**:

I supposed your models.py is similar below:

```
from django.db import models


class Question(models.Model):
    body = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=200)


class Quiz(models.Model):
    questions = models.ManyToManyField(Question)
```

You can make a form class in forms.py for handle this:

```
from django import forms

from models import Quiz, Question

class QuizForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Quiz
        fields = '__all__'

    questions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Question.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

Your views.py file:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from forms import QuizForm

def show(request):
    return render(request, 'qtemplate.html', {'form': QuizForm()})
```

and on the template:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ form }}
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how do i use the formset? I have been on it for long and dont get how to implement it in this scenario

Comment: Hi @Tower, i glad that my answer helped you, open link in my post and read this, by few search in internet you can see many tutorials...

Comment: Hi @Moshen! I appreciate your explanation on using formset. I still couldnt fix it. I edited my question to include the correct model; i believe the form will have to change. A question has many choices(foreignkey), how does the question_text and choices enter the form?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is a good solution, but you can try to move the 'submit' input tag into your form :)

```html
<html>

<body>
  {% for question in latest_question_list %}
  <h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
  {% if error_message %}
  <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong>
  </p>
  {% endif %}
  <form id="qform" action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %} {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="{{ question.id }}" id=”choice{{ forloop.counter }} " value="{{ choice.id }}” />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label>
    <br/>{% endfor %}
  </form>
  <input form="qform" type="submit" value="Vote" />
  {% endfor %}
  
</body>

</html>
```

or you can try to use Django-restframework + some javascript framework (e.g. react) to implement this feature

Comment: Thanks a lot! i tried it but it gave me more than 1 vote button.